# How do I configure SQL Server to allow other users to access a database?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

Environment:

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- SQL Server 2005 Express
- 2 users on the computer

I tried making the 2nd user a user in SQL Server (THINKPAD\2ndUser) and adding him to the database ("2ndUser"). Then, I logged in as 2ndUser and started Visual Studio 2008. When I tried to connect to the database, I got the following error message:

```
The database '<bleep>' does not exist or you do not have permission to see it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the login in two places. The instance and the database. This is done in the security folder for the instance and then the security folder for the database.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: @Zian Choy - What does your event log say? The errors are logged there and are usually quite a bit more detailed.